# Difference between ifstream.good() and bool(ifstream)

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

I'm writing a program which takes several variables from a text file.
When the program finds EOF,
it ends entering data.

```
int main()
{
    int val, count = 0;
    ifstream fileIn;
    fileIn.open("num.txt");

    fileIn >> val;
    while (fileIn)
    {
        ++count;
        cout << "number: " << val << endl;
        fileIn >> val;
    }
    cout << "count: " << count << endl;

    fileIn.close();
    return 0;
}
```

`num.txt` file: `11 22 33 44`

Program output:

```
number: 11
number: 22
number: 33
number: 44
count: 4
```

Everything is OK. But if I change the while condition section from `fileIn` to `fileIn.good()`,
the program output will look like this:

```
number: 11
number: 22
number: 33
count: 3
```

It skips last value now.
Why is this happening and what's the difference between `fileIn`
and `fileIn.good()`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It skips last value now. Why is this happening and what's the
>   difference between `fileIn` and `fileIn.good()`?

```
fileIn >> val;
while (fileIn)
{
    ++count;
    cout << "number: " << val << endl;
    fileIn >> val;
}
```

For a given content of `"11 22 33 44"` in the stream associated with `fileIn`. Using the `bool(fileIn)` [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) will return whether the stream has not failed. Note that reaching [`eof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) isn't failure of the stream. Failure is basically when an I/O operation fails.

So, after reading the last number `44` into `val`. The loop is entered again because the stream has not failed: `count` is incremented, `val` is printed, but the next `fileIn >> val` will fail. Which will then be tested in the while loop's condition, and the failure will cause the loop to exit.

Doing [`fileIn.good()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) returns `false` if any of the stream's [`state flags`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) have been set. Specifically, [`eof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate#The_eofbit), [`fail`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate#The_failbit) and [`bad`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate#The_badbit)

Answer (score 5):

`if (fileIn)` is equivalent to `if (!fileIn.fail())`, which returns true if `badbit` or `failbit` is set in `rdstate()`.

On the other hand `fileIn.good()` checks if `rdstate()` is equal to 0. So in addition to `fail()` it also checks `eofbit` flag of.

> It skips last value now. Why is this happening and what's the difference between fileIn
>   and fileIn.good()?

Because you read `val` then check condition of stream using `while(fileIn.good())` and then output last value, which will never be seen because then `fileIn` has `eofbit` set. Which is not checked by `if(infs)` as stated above.